# Update a field in mongodb document stored in a array of array in yii2 model

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, yii2-advanced-app, database

I have a database in mongodb for restaurants. Sample database is as follows.

```
{
   "restaurantId":"1",
   "menu":
   {
        "menuCategory":
        [
            {
                "menuCategoryId":"12"
                "menuItems":
                [
                    {
                        "menuId":"123",
                        "likesCount":0
                    },
                    {
                        "menuId":"1234",
                        "likesCount":0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "menuCategoryId":"1290"
                "menuItems":
                [
                    {
                        "menuId":"2222",
                        "likesCount":0
                    },
                    {
                        "menuId":"3333",
                        "likesCount":0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
   }
}
```

In this document, I have to either increase or decrease the likes count against the menuId and restaurantId which is received in yii2. I am not able to find the likes count for the particular menuId in the restaurant to update it.

I tried the following query to update the likesCount.

```
db.restaurants.update({$and:[{"restaurantId":"1"},{"menu.menuCategory.menu.menuId":"123"}]}, {$set:{"likesCount":5}})
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to achieve it?

Comment: @Shrabanee I have updated my question with the query I tried.

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:-

```
db.restaurants.update(
{$and:[{"restaurantId":"1"},
{"menu.menuCategory.menuItems.menuId":"123"}]}, 
{$set:{"menu.menuCategory.0.menuItems.0.likesCount":5}})
```

**EDIT**

Try something like below:-

```
 db.restaurants.find(
 {"restaurantId":"1","menu.menuCategory.menuItems.menuId":"123"}).toArray(
function(err, result)
{
    var index,found = false;
  for(var j in result[0].menu.menuCategory){
    for(var i in result[0].menu.menuCategory[j].menuItems)
    {
         if(results[0].menu.menuCategory[j].menuItems[i].menuId == "123")
         {
            found = true;
            index = i;
            break;
        }  
     }}

  if(found)
  {
       var x = 'menu.menuCategory.$.menuItems.'+index+'.likes';

       var  updateObject = {$set : {}};    
       updateObject['$set'][x] = 5;

      db.restaurants.update(
    {"restaurantId":"1",
   "menu.menuCategory.menuItems.menuId":"123"}, updateObject);
  }
});
```

See if this can help you.

Comment: This query I have tried earlier and it gives this error `Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'menu.menuCategory.$.menuItems.$.likesCount'`

Comment: Yes I have tried it. `0` will give the first object in the array, where as it is not compulsory that the required object will be at `0` th position always in both the cases of `$`

Comment: No Its not working, query is getting executed without any errors but there is no update in my database against the menuId. In the above query end it with `)` and add statement separator `;` at the end of the assignment statement of `x` instead of `,`.

Comment: Can you try debugging? Where it is going wrong? Ideally it should work. This is how I am using and it is working fine in my case.

Comment: I tried debugging the, but I didn't find the error. Please let me know the procedure you are following.